# Align, merge and extract values from two different files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started to work with scripts and I need to find out the best way to merge, extract field and align data. 
Example:

filename.csv1:

```
ID a b c d 
ID1 0.95 7.82 1.39 2.81 
ID2 0.39 2.59 1.83 0.93 
ID3 0.3 2.55 1.53 0.89 
ID4 0.27 1.5 1.35 0.6 
ID5 0.38 2.84 1.2 1.01
```

data.csv2:

```
ID,e,f,g
ID1,-939.787,-13.127,7.415
ID2,-940.725,-13.671,2.378
ID3,-944.034,-12.695,2.868
ID4,-932.057,-12.761,2.931
ID5,-935.295,-7.930,3.041
```

I need to extract `b` from `filename.csv1` and `f` from `data.csv2` in one single file to obtain an output file as this:

```
ID,b,f
ID1,7.82,-13.127
ID2,2.59,-13.671
```

what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Read about [ask]. Please post any attemt you made and how it went wrong. If you don't have an attempt, start by doing some research and try to solve your problem, and come here to ask about a specific issue you have, along with a [mre]

Comment: Okay.. I thought I wrote in the correct way.. but obviously I was wrong.